# ValueError: Dataframe must have columns "ds" and "y" with the dates and values respectively

Tags: python, pandas

I have created my data source with ds and y format and am still receiving error as above...please see below code

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import pystan
    from fbprophet import Prophet
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sussmanbl\Desktop\fb prophet ar historical2.csv')
    df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
    print(df.head())
    df.dtypes
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    plt.plot(df.set_index('ds'))
    plt.legend(['AR'])
    m1 = Prophet(weekly_seasonality=True)
    m1 = Prophet(daily_seasonality=True)
    m1.fit(df)
    future = m1.make_future_dataframe(periods=90)
    future.tail().T
    forecast = m1.predict(future)
    forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()
    fig1 = m1.plot(forecast)
    fig2 = m1.plot_components(forecast)

    runfile('C:/Users/sussmanbl/Desktop/Modelling/FB Prophet AR Historical.py', 
    wdir='C:/Users/sussmanbl/Desktop/Modelling')
    Reloaded modules: stanfit4anon_model_ad32c37d592cdbc572cbc332ac6d2ee2_4431954053790800620
    ds y
    0 2017-01-03 10
    1 2017-01-04 39
    2 2017-01-05 19
    3 2017-01-06 12
    4 2017-01-09 11
```

### Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in
runfile('C:/Users/sussmanbl/Desktop/Modelling/FB Prophet AR Historical.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/sussmanbl/Desktop/Modelling')

File "C:\Users\sussmanbl.conda\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\sussmanbl.conda\envs\stan_env\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/sussmanbl/Desktop/Modelling/FB Prophet AR Historical.py", line 17, in
m1.fit(df)

File "C:\Users\sussmanbl.conda\envs\stan_env\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 
1082, in fit

'Dataframe must have columns "ds" and "y" with the dates and '

ValueError: Dataframe must have columns "ds" and "y" with the dates and values respectively.
```

```
    df.dtypes
    Out[46]:
    ds datetime64[ns]
    y int64
    dtype: object
```

i have formatted the source data to be in ds and y format.  the dates are in proper format as are the values.  im not sure what the code or the source data is missing that is causing the value error to come up

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; turns out I had `ds` and `y` capitalized. Once I made them lowercase in the `.csv` file, it all worked as it should.